# Splitting large DEM for solar analysis

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.0, spatial-analyst, solar-radiation

I am trying to run Solar analysis in ArcGIS Desktop and it is an enormous DEM of a very mountainous region.     I am going to have to split the DEM.

Are there any issues with doing this?

For example, if you analyze a section separately from an adjacent mountain that would have shaded this section.

Answer (score 6):

Surrounding topography does have an effect on each pixel as it is analyzed using the solar analysis tools. From ESRI's own documentation:

> ...accounts for atmospheric effects, site latitude and elevation,
>   steepness (slope) and compass direction (aspect), daily and seasonal
>   shifts of the sun angle, and effects of shadows cast by surrounding
>   topography.

More specifically:
[How the viewshed is calculated](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//009z000000t9000000)

> Since radiation can be greatly affected by topography and surface
>   features, a key component of the calculation algorithm requires the
>   generation of an upward-looking hemispherical viewshed for every
>   location in the digital elevation model (DEM).

[image]

It would seem that if you are in a mountainous region and you remove some of those mountains, the nearby pixels will be affected. The documentation doesn't mention anything about these edge effects. A test or possible solution to this issue would be to create overlapping clipped regions. You could recombine these clipped regions based on a rule-set (e.g. use the overlapping region that has the lowest pixel values).

Answer (score 0):

You are also going to want to split the DEM at the pixel line, rather than sub splitting the pixels.  Splitting a pixel can provide interpolation and rounding errors with algorthimns.